# Please help me simplify and translate to dot notation linq query

Tags: c#, performance, linq

```
var query = (from objectType in _session.GetAll<ObjectType>()
  let currentVersion = objectType
      .ObjectTypeVersions.OrderByDescending(x =>x.ObjectTypeVersionId)
      .FirstOrDefault()
  where 
      objectType.Active && 
      currentVersion.Active && 
      objectType.ContentTemplate.Active
  select currentVersion);
```

I have query like this and I don't understand what it does. I would like to rewrite it in method syntax.

Comment: Generally, whenever I need to use a temporary variable in the middle of the query, the query syntax `let` is much cleaner. I'd say your example would be worse in dot notation.

Comment: You don't have `let` keyword in method syntax. Presence of `let` is usually a good reason to use query syntax !

Comment: Yes, but tries were unsuccessful. ( Because I dont familie with query notation

Comment: I wish there were a good equivalent to let, though.  Not a fan of query syntax.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus You can write a `Let` method if you want.  It's pretty trivial to write, really.

Comment: `please help me` sounds more like `do it for me` when you don't show your attempt. Please show your effort so that others may show theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query syntax is just syntactic sugar. You can use a decompiler, like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), to translate to the extension method notation. After some cleaning up, here's what I get:

```
var query = objectTypes.Select(objectType => new
{
    objectType = objectType, 
    currentVersion = objectType.ObjectTypeVersions
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ObjectTypeVersionId).FirstOrDefault()
}).Where(x => x.objectType.Active && x.currentVersion.Active && 
    x.objectType.ContentTemplate.Active).Select(x => x.currentVersion);
```

For reference, this is the raw code ILSpy produced...basically the same thing, but with a generated variable name that's not a valid C# identifier, and unnecessarily explicit typing.

```
IEnumerable<ObjectTypeVersion> query = objectTypes.Select((ObjectType objectType) => new
{
    objectType = objectType,
    currentVersion = objectType.ObjectTypeVersions.OrderByDescending((ObjectTypeVersion x) => x.ObjectTypeVersionId).FirstOrDefault<ObjectTypeVersion>()
}).Where(<>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.objectType.Active && <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.currentVersion.Active && <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.objectType.ContentTemplate.Active).Select(<>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.currentVersion);
```

Comment: @Sergey No, I suppose there's no difference with your code. I'm not sure whether that means I should delete my answer...I arrived at it independently, and I think the advice of using a decompiler is useful.

Comment: Ah, I see. But decompiler would show ugly code, trust me :)

Comment: @Sergey True! In fact, I've edited my answer to include that, for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go with query syntax. But here is lambda syntax:

```
var query = _session.GetAll<ObjectType>()
     .Select(objectType => new {
          objectType,
          currentVersion = objectType.ObjectTypeVersions.OrderByDescending(otv => otv.ObjectTypeVersionId).FirstOrDefault()
      }).Where(x => x.objectType.Active && x.currentVersion.Active && x.objectType.ContentTemplate.Active)
        .Select(x => x.currentVersion);
```

Main idea here is creation of anonymous type, which holds original query variable `objectType` and second one `currenVersion` introduced by `let` keyword.

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain what's wrong with this query? Thanks